# How to connect Zeppelin to Spark Master in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I've installed Spark and Zeppeline on Kubernetes using helm chart incubator/Spark

In the Zeppeline interpreter, the Spark's master is set to local[*]
Then, I changed to spark://ClusterIP_Spark_Master:7077

However, it seems that the interpreter cannot connect to Spark Master.

Is there any solution for this?
Do I need to export SPARK_HOME?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I installed Spark 2.2.0 on docker image apache/zeppelin and set the SPARK_HOME to the Spark directory, I changed the url to spark://spark-master:7077.

Zeppelin can now connect to my Spark cluster.

[The docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/clouderjustmakeit/zeppelinspark/)  I built with spark installed in /spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: What SPARK_HOME should it be set to? I have a separate spark cluster on other machine, should I also install spark on the same machine as Zeppelin?

Comment: SPARK_HOME should be set to the Spark you install on your Zeppelin machine. yes you should also do that.

Comment: Why isn't the Dockerfile visible in the interface??

Comment: @Angelito the image was uploaded manually not by automated builds.

Comment: I was planning to use this method to connect my local Zeppelin to EMR master but it did not work. Did I miss something? spark://ec2-address:7070